# Why isn't my htaccess RewriteRule working for my query strings?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am moving an ASPX site to Wordpres -- from an IIS server to Apache -- and I am having problems getting the pages with query strings to redirect. I looked into the Apache documentation and am trying to use mod_rewrite, but so far no luck.

For example I would like to redirect these pages:

> www.mysite/Product/Product.aspx?mapid=324$    to
>   www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget7/
>   www.mysite/Product/Product.aspx?mapid=681$    to
>   www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget12/
>   www.mysite/Product/Product.aspx?mapid=841$    to
>   www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget82/

Here is where I am at. I have tried several iterations of this but can't get it to work. I am starting to think that it might have something to do with first few Rules, which were generated by the server and Wordpress. The site is an addon domain, which the server treats like a subdomain.

My rewrites are the last three. Any ideas why these aren't working? Thanks for any help.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~username/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /~username/mysite/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=324$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/Product/Product\.aspx(.*)$ ^https://www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget7/? [L,R=302,NC]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=681$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/Product/Product\.aspx(.*)$ ^https://www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget12/? [L,R=302,NC]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=841$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/Product/Product\.aspx(.*)$ ^https://www.mysite/blue-widgets/widget82/? [L,R=302,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=324$ [NC]
RewriteRule /Product/Product\.aspx https://www.example.com/blue-widgets/widget7/? [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=681$ [NC]
RewriteRule /Product/Product\.aspx https://www.example/blue-widgets/widget12/? [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mapid=841$ [NC]
RewriteRule /Product/Product\.aspx https://www.example/blue-widgets/widget82/? [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~username/mysite/index.php [L]
```

To better explain for others, the order of the rules is important. Since the Wordpress rules change the RewriteBase and change the URL the rules for the .aspx pages will never be hit if they are at the bottom.

Comment: So order of operations is important? Move my rules above the RewriteBase? Still doesn't seem to be working, but I'll play around with it some more. Thanks.

Comment: I also changed your rules. Try exactly what I have.